# What does Epson windows driver "Share Network User Settings" do?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, network-printer

What does the Epson windows driver Version Information >> Client Settings >> "Share Network User Settings" setting do?

By context I would think this means page sizes & colour configurations etc. could be shared to and used by other people, but this isn't happening for us (and/or I don't see how access it).

The phrases "Share Network User Settings", "User Settings" & "Share Network" do not appear in [the manuals](https://epson.ca/Support/Printers/Single-Function-Inkjet-Printers/Epson-Stylus-Series/Epson-Stylus-Pro-9900/s/SPT_SP9900HDR#manuals) (500+ pages) and shorter combinations have too many results (though I'm still looking through them).

[image: Epson Driver "Version Information" screen shot]

Comment: It means that each time a user, changes the printer configuration, it would be changed for all users.  It isn't working because the "auto" URI configuration, isn't applicable, to your network apparently.  It would be the address you have assigned to your printer.  *Of course given the fact, its on the version tab, it might actually mean it communicates with Epson.*  I would call Epson and ask if I had this printer.

Comment: @Ramhound. I've reached out to Epson via web contact form and twitter. We'll see what comes back. ... "changed for all users" Oh, so it's same as what 'Print Properties >> Advanced >> Preferences' but without needing mange/admin privileges?

Comment: @Ramhound - By twitter Epson responded by saying search the support website. The Epson email response featured your comment copy and pasted verbatim, without bothering to change formatting or credit source. You should bill them. ;-)  [I made mistake of referencing this post for more information]. While waiting for the cheque to arrive, change your comment to answer and at least get rep points.